# Android Google Analytics: set Mobile Device Info

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

The latest version of Google Analytics has a Mobile category under Visitors. However, Visitors > Mobile > Devices shows only one value, (not set), for my visits.

I am using the latest SDK (1.3). How can I set the Mobile Device Info (custom var, method I am not seeing) so that it appears in the report?

Comment: mobile will be registered only if u have separate tag defined for it in the code. you can find the details for tagging it on the Google Analytics site. Could even be that your google analytics tracking code is older than the one that supports mobile distinction.

Comment: I created the UA-## yesterday. Do you have a more specific reference for the details?

Comment: @Piyush I am using Android Analytics SDK, no tracking code (JavaScript). Do you have a link to the details you reference on the Google Analytics site?

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html#ga:isMobile

Comment: I am looking for a way to have Mobile Device Info set. isMobile is already being set to Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue testing the Android SDK (v2 beta 5). It turned out to be ridiculously obvious after I spent far too much time trying to solve the issue in code and `analytics.xml`. This may not be the OP's problem, but this is where I ended up looking when I had the same issue, so I hope it helps. Long story short...

**Emulator device info can confuse Google Analytics**

I was testing a lot of these calls on an emulator. Even though my custom emulator was based roughly on a Galaxy Nexus (`hw.device.manufacture: Google` and `hw.device.name: Galaxy Nexus` according to Android Virtual Device Manager, it was coming over as `Manufacturer = "unknown"` and `Model = "Android SDK built for x86"` at runtime. As a result, Google Analytics decided that constitutes "(not set)" for just about ever device property they stored.

Once I was deployed to a physical test device, all the appropriate data was pulled in automatically by the SDK.

Comment: I'm not in a position to confirm (and won't be for a while unfortunately), but will accept this as it seems to make sense

Answer (score 0):

The information in "Visitors > Mobile > Devices" is automatically filled in by the SDK ([based on the HTTP User-Agent string](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/platform#ga%3amobileDeviceBranding)], and automatically, if possible, classified by Analytics.

Google seems to have problems identifying new devices when they come out (if they change their browser ID strings, etc), so you'll see "(not set)" for traffic from those devices.  For example, see http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-google-analytics-features-with-other-users/n-LDtWGhZiY (after the iOS 5 release, these devices showed up as "(not set)" Mobile Devices for several months).